# Limit Child record fetched in JPA Eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have a parent entity that has a list of child entities. There are some new child entities that are created and set to the parent entity. Code Snippet is shown below.

```
public class ParentEntity {
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="parentField", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<ChildEntityA> childAList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class BusinessLogic {
 public void methodA() {
   ParentEntity parent = parentRepository.getById();
   parent.setFieldA("fieldA");
   ChildEntityA child1 = new ChildEntityA();
   child1.setField1("field1");
   ChildEntityA child2 = new ChildEntityA();
   child2.setField1("field1");
   List<ChildEntityA> childAList = new ArrayList<>();
   childAList.add(child1);
   childAList.add(child2);
   parent.setChildAList(childAList);//This triggers a select call on DB table associated with Child A and fetches all the records
   entityManager.merge(parent);
}
}
```

My problem is parent.setChildAList(childAList); triggers a SELECT query on the child DB table and is fetching millions of records that are not needed. Is there a way to limit the number of child records that are retrieved or prevent that all together? The select all is causing GC thrashing and is affecting the performance.

JPA is the specification and Eclipselink is my provider. 
Any help on this will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't want to fetch it on access, don't map it. Use your own query to fetch the related records using pagination if/when they are required. Otherwise, having it in the model with cascade options set means it has to be brought into memory, in its entirety, for JPA to manage at some point. EclipseLink, if using change tracking, would allow you to add to the existing list without fetching it, but since you are replacing the list entirely it must be fetched.

Comment: This code is wrong, as you are replacing the full list with one with 2 values, ignoring the child objects still pointing to the parent.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wanted to clarify that I am not replacing the list entirely. In my above example, the parentEntity might have a million child records associated with it. I am only inserting 2 new ones. I am not modifying any of the existing child records. Let me try @ChangeTracking annotation.